# swaping the highest element to the last postion but it doesnot print the list after swaping the elements

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to swap the last item with the biggest number in the list but it doesn't print anything

```
a=[3,4,2,2,43,7]
maxindex=0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] is max(a):
        maxno = a[i]
        maxindex = i
if a[maxindex] < a[len(a)-1]:
    a[maxindex],a[len(a)-1] = a[len(a)-1],a[maxindex] 
    print(a)
```

expected result is `[3,4,2,2,7,43]`

Comment: I think your last if condition is wrong: `if a[maxindex] > a[len(a)-1]:`

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: **1** Why are you computing `max(a)` on every loop iteration? You should do that outside the loop. **2** Don't use `is` to compare values, use `==`. `is` compares the _identity_ of objects, not their values, and although it will give correct results in some cases (like comparing small integers), it won't always work. Eg, try this: `print(260 is 26*10)`. **3** You don't need to do `a[len(a)-1]`, Python lets you write that as `a[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Find indices of the two numbers. Assign them to two separate variables. Then, swap them, like so:

```
>>> a = [3,4,2,2,43,7]
>>> last_index = a.index(a[-1])
>>> max_num_index = a.index(max(a))
>>> a[last_index], a[max_num_index] = a[max_num_index], a[last_index]
>>> a
[3, 4, 2, 2, 7, 43]
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
a = [3,43,2,2,43,7]
maximum = max(a)
for index,data in enumerate(a):
         if data == maximum:
             a[index] = a[-1]
a[-1] = maximum
print a
```

Method 2[Using list comprehension]:

```
a = [a[-1] if data == maximum else data for index,data in enumerate(a)]
a[-1] = maximum
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
a=[3,4,2,2,74, 300,70]
a[a.index(max(a))], a[-1] = a[-1], a[a.index(max(a))]
print(a)
```

Remark: this works only for none duplicated max elements.

Comment: True, thank you! I guess one can say it only works correctly for none duplicated max elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in a simple way: swapping the max item with the last item, by finding the position of the max item

```
a = [3,4,2,2,43,7]

a[a.index(max(a))], a[-1] = a[-1], a[a.index(max(a))]

print(a)
```

#### output:

```
[3, 4, 2, 2, 7, 43]
```

To add efficiency (as was pointed out by PM2Ring in the comments), and avoid finding max twice (an O(n) operation), you can first save the index in a variable, and use it in the swap:

```
a = [3,4,2,2,43,7]
max_index = a.index(max(a))
a[max_index], a[-1] = a[-1], a[max_index]

print(a)
```

Comment: Why compute `a.index(max(a))` twice? `max` and `.index` both require a linear scan of the list, so doing those scans twice is rather inefficeient.

Comment: *swap the **last** item with the biggest number*. This fails for `[3, 4, 43, 2, 2, 43, 7]`.

Comment: You are raising a good point, however, in view of the OP's code, I thought that explaining how to do it was more important than efficiency. I'll add your remark in the answer nonetheless. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly fails Moses Koledoye? In case of several identical maxes, the behavior required was not defined by the OP.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque You may be right, however, I seem to have deduced this from how the index is supposedly updated in their code.

Comment: what if i wanted for it to happen recursively that is sort the whole list but after every loop ignore the highest number as it's sorted

Comment: You should accept this answer and ask a new question.